# Set SuiteClassess from Properties file and indtentify properties file in command line

Tags: java, selenium, command-line, junit, selenium-webdriver

Hi I would like to know if it is possible to set the suite classes to be used from a properties file like so (**test.properties**):

> test = CorrectTestBackLink.class, CorrectTestSaveToDatabase.class, ErrorTestEnterLetterCalc.class, ErrorTestLeaveBlankCalc.class

or like this

> test1 = CorrectTestBackLink.class
>
> test2 = CorrectTestSaveToDatabase.class
>
> test3 = ErrorTestEnterLetterCalc.class
>
> test4 = ErrorTestLeaveBlankCalc.class

and then do something like this I know suite class needs classes so im not sure how to get the list to it.

```
@Suite.SuiteClasses({selectproperties.propertyarray});
// the actual class is empty
public class RunSelected {}
```

with **SelectedProperties.class** having something like this so that it gets it as an array.

```
public String propertyArray;
public String propertyFileName;
public class SelectedProperties{
            System.in(propertyFileName);
            prop.load(new FileInputStream(propertyFileName));
            propertyArray = prop.getProperty("test");
    }
```

Then run it using this **command line**:

> java -cp bin;libs/junit-4.8.1.jar;libs/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;libs/selenium-java-2.34.0.jar;libs/guava-14.0.jar;libs/json-20080701.jar;libs/commons-exec-1.1.jar;libs/httpcore-4.2.1.jar;libs/httpclient-4.2.1.jar;libs/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;libs/mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar;libs/cpsuite-1.1.0.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore test.RunSelected

but I want to be able to set the **propertyFileName** in the command not sure how, but by ending it with something like **"test.properties"**.

I will appreciate any help given. I plan on scheduling and executing these tests through Jenkins. I know the code is completely wrong but its just to show my idea.

Answer (score 1):

I havent used JUnit so cannot give the code for SuiteClasses. About passing the properties file name from command line - you can pass that to the main() method and add logic in SelectedProperties to read the properties file and split the comma separated values for "test" property. And then pass that as an array to the SuiteClasses.

I actually implemented similar idea using TestNG. But instead of passing the classes from properties file, i do it from excel sheet. The sheet has class names and execution flag columns. Based on the execution flags, the TestNG xml is created dynamically and executed.

Comment: Ill have a look into this thanks, my biggest issue is that Suite.SuiteClasses expects class literal in the ({x.class, y.class}) for example.